# RSS blending of multiple feeds to one. Any Good Script out there?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I have a multiple blogs and authors. Now what i want to make a activity feed for author's profile pages which will show the recent posts of an author by rss feed. Author will be given a textbox to add there rss feed urls which i want to marge in one and show by date published.

Now i have searched for rss mixer script but did not found any good ones. There are some web services. But as i will show the feeds by users given rss scripts so i need to do it in server. So i need some good php script to do it.

The site is hosted in wordpress. Some advices me using wordpress plugins but i don't wanna do it because the theme i making will use in lots of sites. Installing the plugin individually will be a pain.

So, is there any rss mixer script out there with proper cache management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplepie http://simplepie.org/ gave me the best solution for it. Using simple pie it is really easy to mix multiple rss feeds to one.